# Making WordPress available while logged into another website

Tags: users, password

A bit of a tricky one this and I'm not sure the best way to proceed or even if there is way to proceed.

We have a self-hosted, secure, members-only website running off Oracle and IIS. Members sign up, get a username, password and PIN (via PIN mailer). They can then access this site and go about their business.

Our model is to build simple stand alone brochure sites in WordPress hosted on a shared hosting plan that acts as a portal to this secure site. This model has worked fine for years as there has never been a need for overlap between the two.

We have a customer asking that the WordPress site be locked down and accessible only via a username and password.

We are trying to work out a way to allow access to the WP site if someone has logged into our secure site. Or to see if there is a way we can use the credentials from one on the other without need to recreate the user in WP.

Heads are being banged off tables at this stage so I am throwing this one out to see if people better placed than us have a solution.

I can provide any additional information that might be required.

Thanks in advance.
G

Comment: [`wp_authenticate()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_authenticate) is a [pluggable function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pluggable_Functions), so you can replace it with your own functionality.  You'd need to write a function to authenticate against your username/PIN system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The function `wp_authenticate` is pluggable](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L468), meaning you can override it with a function of your own of the same name. You could rewrite that to contact your "self-hosted, secure, members-only website" for logins instead of using the WordPress login system.

There are other pluggable functions in that file, like `wp_validate_auth_cookie`, which may prove useful [with enough effort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084114/cross-domain-cookies).

Comment: I will focus my efforts here then. I was unaware of this but having had a quick look this would definitely seem to be where I should be looking.

Thanks.